# Get Top n data from a set of grouped data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm on MySQL 5.7 and have a dataset as the table, `bundles`.

| bundle_id | single_amount | item_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 20 | 3 |
| 3 | 15 | 2 |

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/823c91/1/0

e.g. The table means that for bundle1, a customer bought one item that is $100 and another customer bought 3 items that the individual one is $20.

I want to get the top n data by individual item, not by a bundle. The straightforward idea is to  flatten the data as the table below.

| single_amount | item_count |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 20 | 3 |
| 20 | 3 |
| 20 | 3 |
| 15 | 2 |
| 15 | 2 |

It's easy to do it on service but considering the potential size of the dataset, is there a way to do it on MySQL side?

Comment: An idea example : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ab83de88ac775c6285a7485c5a5ff81b . The larger `item_count` is, the longer the query will be. Might have big hit on performance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to create one table having one number column and fill it with 1 to maximum numbers that is available in the column item_count.

Let's say, you have created table as `numbers_table (number_col)`

Then you can use that numbers table as follows:

```
select single_amount, item_count
  from your_table t 
  join numbers_table n on t.item_count >= n.number_col
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8+ supports recursive CTEs (and actually CTEs in general).  But earlier versions do not.  To solve this, you need a numbers table of some sort.  MySQL doesn't have one built-in, but you can generate one.

Based on your description of the problem, the `bundles` table is big enough, so you can use that:

```
SELECT n.n, b.*
FROM bundles b JOIN
     (SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as n
      FROM bundles b CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
      LIMIT 100
     ) n
     ON n.n <= b.item_count;
```

The `LIMIT 100` is just for performance.  You obviously need as many rows at the maximum `item_count`.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/823c91/3) is a SQL Fiddle.